# Problems invoking windows service using Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, service, windows-services, scheduled-tasks

I have created a windows service.

I want to invoke it repeatedly for every 5 seconds through out the day.

I had scheduled a windows task to do that but the windows service doesnt seem to get invoked when invoked from the windows task.

I am using `NET START "Windows Service Name.exe" to schedule task under windows task scheduler.

It runs properly when I manually try to start the service.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the solution..!!

Added a new windows task to close the service using NET STOP command.

This helped me.

Hope this helps others. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is incorrect. Instead of starting the service every 5 seconds, your service should start only once and do something every 5 seconds.

The service main function should have a loop which starts when your service is initialized and ends only when the service is stopped (for example when the computer is shutdown). This loop can check for a stop message or event.

Inside the loop you can also perform the operation you want every 5 seconds. You can use a timer or a simple Sleep(5000). You can also do this on a separate thread so it doesn't hold off the timer.

If your starting the service every 5 seconds, why use a service at all?

Answer (score 1):

what OS are you using?

I'm not getting it completely though. 
A service is something you start automatically or manually and once it runs, it runs, until you stop the service.
A Task is something that you can control when and how it will fire and under which credentials it will run and what file it should execute.

I'm reading Your question thus as : you've got a bat file that has the 'net start...' cmd in it and that bat file you want to run every 5 seconds?

Comment: As far as I know, when we start a service, it executes whatever is written on the `OnStart` Event but doesnt keep on repeating that. I have written `NET START` command under Windows Task Scheduler under the Run section. I am using Windows Server 2003. And I dont have any bat file.